# save result to variable

Tags: bash, netcat

How can I save result from nc to the variable?

I want:

> nc: connect to localhost port 1 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

on my variable. I tried:

```
a="$(nc -z -v localhost 1)"
echo $a
```

but output is empty.

Comment: So you want to capture the error output?

Answer (score 14):

Just use `$()` to get the result of the command:

```
your_var=$(nc -z -v localhost 1)
```

If you also want the error to be stored, then redirect the `2` (error) to `1` (normal output):

```
your_var=$(nc -z -v localhost 1 2>&1)
```

Comment: 2>&1 saved me, I was going nuts!

Comment: Holy, I never realised $() is saving the output only of stdout. Thought I was retarded or Bash doesn't work. xD

Answer (score 4):

Just redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, expressed by `2>&1`:

```
a="$(nc -z -v localhost 1 2>&1)"
echo $a
nc: connect to localhost port 1 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

File descriptor `2` is attached (unless redirected) to `stderr`, and `fd 1` is attached to `stdout`. The  `bash` syntax `$( ... )` only captures `stdout`.

Answer (score 2):

`-w` is your friend in this case

> -w timeout
>   Connections which cannot be established or are idle timeout after timeout seconds.  The -w flag has no effect on the -l option, i.e. nc will listen forever for a connection, with or without the -w flag.  The default is no timeout.

```
nc -z -w 3 $serverName $serverPort
```

Now you can use the $? variable to use it in your script.

`if [ $? == 0 ]` can be used to use the output of above command in the scripts.
Above command will timeout the connection after 3 seconds if it not able to establish.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might come across this question by searching or from google, wondering why a successful connection saved to a `$var` returns an empty string, according to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/e3h4z1/nc_prints_to_stderr_instead_of_stdout_am_i_going/) "All messages from nc itself, as opposed to from the socket, are printed to stderr." So as mentioned by fedorqui and Mickael, you have to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` even though it doesn't seem like you're getting an error message.

Example of output to terminal but empty output when calling your `$var`:

`var=$(nc -z -w 10 www.google.com 80)` outputs `Connection to www.google.com port 80 [tcp/http] succeeded!` to the terminal, but when calling `echo $var` it displays an empty string even though the connection was successful.

Example of saving the `stderr` output to the `$var`:

`var=$(nc -z -w 10 www.google.com 80 2>&1)` runs the nc command, then calling `echo $var` no longer outputs an empty string, but instead the expected success message `Connection to www.google.com port 80 [tcp/http] succeeded!`.